# Unexpected page breaks with parallel package

Tags: page-breaking, parallel

I am trying to use the package parallel to typeset some text in two languages. The text in language A should appear on even pages, the text in language B on odd pages. I typeset

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parallel}

\begin{document}
\begin{Parallel}[p]{}{}
\ParallelLText{Hello}
\ParallelRText{Hallo}
\ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{Hello}
\ParallelRText{Hallo}
\ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody know why the parallel package breaks the page after the first `\ParallelPar`? That is, why do I get 5 pages output instead of 3? Is this a feature or a bug of the package or did I do something wrong?

Comment: I think it's a feature.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to avoid it?

Comment: It is a feature. Talk to the maintainer of the package. Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164830